# Comparing a Date with the current Date results in NumberFormatException

Tags: java, android, string, integer, simpledateformat

I'm trying to compare a date/time (that I saved in a SharedPreferences) with the current date/time.

With this I'm checking when the last time was that the service did ran, and if it is necessary to run again.

I'm converting the current date to an integer. But then I get an error:
Error:

> 08-27 17:21:40.930: W/System.err(26577): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "201308271721"

Full error:

> 08-27 17:21:40.930: W/System.err(26577): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "201308271721"
>   08-27 17:21:40.960: W/System.err(26577):   at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
>   08-27 17:21:40.960: W/System.err(26577):   at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:378)
>   08-27 17:21:40.960: W/System.err(26577):   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
>   08-27 17:21:40.960: W/System.err(26577):   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
>   08-27 17:21:40.960: W/System.err(26577):   at 
>   xxx.xxx.RoosterSync.onHandleIntent(RoosterSync.java:118)
>   08-27 17:21:40.960: W/System.err(26577):   at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
>   08-27 17:21:40.960: W/System.err(26577):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   08-27 17:21:40.960: W/System.err(26577):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   08-27 17:21:40.960: W/System.err(26577):   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

The (peace of) code i'm using:

```
Date now = new Date();
String nowAsString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm").format(now);
dayNow= Integer.parseInt(nowAsString);
```

Is it possible to convert a date-string to an integer?

Or am I doing something stupid and is there an easier way?

Comment: you should learn java basics http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE

Comment: Sounds like a pretty innocent mistake to me. Do not think it's worthy of a close vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This value is too long for 32-bit integer. Please try using a long instead.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html for type limits.

A related question is why do you want to store a date-time in such a format. UNIX timestamp (which BTW, should definitely be a `long` too) is way more convenient to store and manipulate - see Calendar.getTimeInMillis.

This is a format which allows easy date comparison and storage.

Comment: I thought that an int could do more than this. Thanks, i'm going to use an long instead!

Answer (score 1):

Just try,

> Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong(rowItem.getDatetime()));